# Composer: Is it possible to split processes?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to split install/update/require/remove processes of Composer to execute stage by stage with a web interface? May be like this:

1. User inputs required package name. Client (browser) sends it to web server.
2. Controller gets and returns a number of available repos via AJAX
3. Client sends each repo number until controller returns success.
4. Client sends request to run installation from target repo.
5. Controller installs the package without its dependencies, saves and returns dependencies list to client.
6. Go to stage 1, client sends package name from the list and repeat this with each package till the list ends.
7. When all dependencies are done, client sends a command to create new autoloader.

(Stages 1-3 are definitely implementable, I found some examples of `Composer\Repository\RepositoryManager` using)

So we save a lot of memory and CPU time making the processes possible to execute via web interface.

This is primitive scheme, it will be executed for a long time and needs to be optimized but something like is enough to install lightweight CMS plugins, for example.

Comment: Couldn't you do this by running [composer show](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show) and [composer require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) separately from your code?

Comment: If I had to do this and use web interface, I'd never use Composer. It'd be so ridiculously slow to do all that, compared to a few commands that I can script anyway. But, to answer your question - yes, the probability for that to be possible is pretty high. The premise that you save a lot of memory... well, is it really worth it? Time of the developer costs more than some hardware resources, and I never had composer run for a long time. Plus, there's always [parallel downloader](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo)

Comment: @JimWright I can run them separately but `composer require` is not executabe via web. It requires too much memory and more than 30 sec. This solution is not for web.

Comment: @N.B. I see no other solution for modern CMS to allow third-party developers to use Composer packages. Or coarse: just disable installing plugins via admin interface and make it only via SSH.